# Why is HttpClient.SendAsync throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have a C# application that's acting as sort of a pseudo HTTP proxy for an external REST API. I'm listening for requests using `System.Net.HttpListener` and forwarding them upstream using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. Once I get a response I send if back to the original requester (the client). If I get an exception while doing this I return a 400 status code to the client and a simple web page with the `exception.ToString()`. It naively assumes that if it couldn't get where it was asked to go, it's the client's fault because the URL is bad, etc.

This is basically all I'm doing:

```
private async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    try {
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();

        //Some code to set up the requestMessage

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //Some code to set up the context.Response

        using (Stream s = context.Response.OutputStream) {
            byte[] replyContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            s.Write(replyContent, 0, replyContent.Length);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            Trace.TraceWarning("Unable to handle request.\r\n{0}", e.ToString());
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "Bad Request";
            context.Request.Headers.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.ProtocolVersion = context.Request.ProtocolVersion;
            context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
            context.Response.SendChunked = false;
            using (Stream s = context.Response.OutputStream) {
                byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" +
                    "<html lang=\"en\">\r\n" +
                    "    <head>\r\n" +
                    "        <meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" />\r\n" +
                    "        <title>Error</title>\r\n" +
                    "    </head>\r\n" +
                    "    <body>\r\n" +
                    "        <h1>Error: Unable to handle request.</h1>\r\n" +
                    "        <pre>" + e.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;")
                                                  .Replace("<", "&lt;")
                                                  .Replace(">", "&gt;") + "</pre>\r\n" +
                    "    </body>\r\n" +
                    "</html>\r\n");
                context.Response.ContentLength64 = content.Length;
                s.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }
        } catch (Exception f) {
            Trace.TraceError("Could not send response back to requester.\r\n{0}", f.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is sometimes a 502 (Bad Gateway) status will throw an exception and cause the client to receive HTTP status code 400, but sometimes it doesn't and the client gets the correct 502 status code. I would like to always return the right HTTP status code if I get one.

Here's the exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Runner.Runner.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
```

EDIT:

Below is the code that calls `ProcessRequestAsync`. `server` is the name of my `HttpListener` and this code is running as a Windows service.

```
public void Start()
{
    server.Start();
    Task.Run(async () => {
        while (true)
            try {
                var context = await server.GetContextAsync();
                // I'm using Task.Run here without await so I can
                // immediately listen for another request
                Task.Run(() => ProcessRequestAsync(context));
            } catch (HttpListenerException) {
                break; // Listener stopped.
            } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
                break; // Listener stopped.
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: So are you saying that sometimes you get an exception with a 502, and other times you get a normal response with a status code of 502?

Comment: Yes, sometimes the 502 status doesn't throw an exception depending on where it's coming from. I'm not exactly sure why it would but I'd like it to never throw an exception for this and give me the status code instead.

Comment: @AlexC Where is he blocking?

Comment: `using (Stream s = context.Response.OutputStream)` Looks like you are destroying the response object before you're done with it.

Comment: That is true. If I get an exception while sending the first response I'll get another exception when trying to send the stack trace. I'll make the necessary changes to fix this but I still don't think this is the root of the issue.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but because this request is occurring on the web server and it seems you are directly manipulating the current request shouldn't you change `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `ConfigureAwait(true)`? This because you want to continue with the thread that is affiliated with the current HttpContext, with it set to `false` it would be random depending on which thread the O/S feels like you should continue on. This would be a change for all occurrences (*I see 2 now*) in this method. Not sure how this works with the passed in `HttpListenerContext` but I would assume it is affected.